# RISC-V linker throwing sections LMA overlap error despite LMA's belonging to different memory regions

Tags: c, embedded, ld, riscv, linker-scripts

I've following memory region descriptions in my linker file:

```
/*=============================
 * Memory region descriptions
 *=============================*/

MEMORY
{
  /*-------------------------------------
   * Virtual Memory Address (VMA) regions
   *-------------------------------------*/

  /* Local memory VMA */
  DMEM_VMA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 4K

  /* DRAM text VMA */
  DRAM_T_VMA (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 16M

  /* DRAM data VMA */
  DRAM_D_VMA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x81000000, LENGTH = 2032M /* 2048M - 16M */


  /*----------------------------------
   * Load Memory Address (LMA) regions
   *----------------------------------*/

  /* Local memory LMA */
  DMEM_LMA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x1000, LENGTH = 4K

  /* DRAM text LMA */
  DRAM_T_LMA (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 16M

  /* DRAM data LMA */
  DRAM_D_LMA (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x01000000, LENGTH = 2032M
}



/*=============================
 * Output section descriptions
 *=============================*/

SECTIONS
{

  /*----------------------------------
   * DMEM output sections
   *----------------------------------*/

  /* data segment */
  .data.dmem : { 
    *(.data) 
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA

  .sdata.dmem : {
    _gp = . + 0x800;
    *(.srodata.cst16) *(.srodata.cst8) *(.srodata.cst4) *(.srodata.cst2) *(.srodata*)
    *(.sdata .sdata.* .gnu.linkonce.s.*)
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA


  /* bss segment */
  .sbss.dmem : {
    *(.sbss .sbss.* .gnu.linkonce.sb.*)
    *(.scommon)
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA

  .bss.dmem : { 
    *(.bss) 
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA


  /* thread-local data segment */
  .tdata.dmem : {
    _tls_data = .;
    *(.tdata)
    *(.tdata*)
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA

  .tbss.dmem : {
    *(.tbss)
    *(.tbss*)
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA


  /* read-only data */
  .rodata.dmem : { 
    *(.rodata) 
    *(.rodata*) 
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA


  .eh_frame.dmem : { 
    *(.eh_frame) 
    *(.eh_frame*) 
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA


  /* striped data */
  /* RISC-V 32 has a 4 byte word size */
  .striped.data.dmem ALIGN(bsg_group_size * 4): {
    _bsg_striped_data_start = . ;
    *(.striped.data)
  } >DMEM_VMA AT>DMEM_LMA


  /*----------------------------------
   * DRAM output sections
   *----------------------------------*/

  .text.dram : {
     *crt.o(.text)
     *(.text)
     *(.text.startup)
  } >DRAM_T_VMA AT>DRAM_T_LMA

  .data.dram : {
    *(.dram)
  } >DRAM_D_VMA AT>DRAM_D_LMA
}
```

We have two different regions called DMEM and DRAM and they are physically different memories in our architecture. But, I'm facing the following error for some of the programs I'm trying to link with this link script:

```
riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: section .data.dmem LMA [0000000000001000,000000000000100f] overlaps section .text.dram LMA [0000000000000000,0000000000001e4f]
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm confused why is linker complaining about overlap between two different LMA regions! Any hints for debugging this would be really helpful...

Comment: Perhaps because the 16M region starting at zero, clearly overlaps the 4K region starting at 4K?

Comment: @Clifford Since they are different load memory regions (physically different memories, one is sram and the other is dram), I suppose they can have overlapping addresses. Load addresses are overlapping but the two memories are different.

Comment: If you *suppose* then you don't *know*. ;-) How does the processor differentiate between both memories if they have the same address? That is, which memory is accessed at the address 0x1000?

Comment: If the two memories are different, they must have different physical addresses.  They cannot overlap.  The address is the address on the memory device within the _processor's_ memory map, not an offset from the start of the memory device.

Comment: @Clifford, @ thebusybee One is data memory and the other is instruction memory. Both start at 0 in our architecture -- Harvard architecture. Even the processor memory map has overlap! Is there a way to write linker scripts for these kind of architectures?

Comment: @vb000 : But the linker is not aware of the memory architecture.  Typically in such devices the memories (or at least one of them) is mirrored at a higher region to accommodate this - for the linker you specify the alternate mapping.  I am not familiar with your device, so cannot advise.